# Android: AlertDialog Button not accepting style

Tags: java, android, xml, styles

I've got a style set up for my Alert Dialog, and the style is being shown on [most] of the dialog without issue, the only problem are the buttons.

The phone is an HTC Evo running SenseUI, and the AlertDialog buttons continue to be skinned via the SenseUI theme.  I have tried changing my application style (rtg_style) to be a child of Theme.Dialog instead of Theme.Light.NoTitleBar, and the buttons for the activities continue to be styled correctly, but the AlertDialogs also continue to be styled inccorrectly.  I'm trying to avoid having to write a completely custom AlertDialog replacement, what else can I do?

styles.xml:

```
<style name="rtg_style" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bluebg</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/rtg_Button</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/rtg_ListView</item>
    <item name="android:expandableListViewStyle">@style/rtg_ExpandableListView</item>
</style>

<style name="rtg_AlertDialog" parent="@style/rtg_style"> <!-- parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"> --> 
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/rtg_Button</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/rtg_ListView</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/dialog</item>
</style>

<style name="rtg_Button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:height">40dp</item>
</style>

<style name="rtg_ListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/listview</item>
</style>

<style name="rtg_ExpandableListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ExpandableListView">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/listview</item>
</style>    

<style name="base">
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
</style>    

<style name="title" parent="@style/base">
      <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="body" parent="@style/base">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>

<style name="dialog">
    <item name="android:fullDark">@drawable/dialog_body</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@drawable/dialog_title</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@drawable/dialog_body</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@drawable/dialog_footer</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@drawable/dialog_body</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@drawable/dialog_body</item>
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@drawable/dialog_footer</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@drawable/dialog_footer</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@drawable/dialog_body</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>

</style>
```

Activity.java:

```
AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(OrderSummary.this, R.style.rtg_AlertDialog));
            ab.setTitle("Select a reason");
            String[] reasons = new String[Shared.Reasons_RejectAll.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < Shared.Reasons_RejectAll.size(); i++) { 
                try {
                    reasons[i] = Shared.Reasons_RejectAll.get(i).Name;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            ab.setItems(reasons, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    rejectReason = Shared.Reasons_RejectAll.get(which).Name;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= r.ItemList.length; i++){
                        r.ItemList[index].item.get(i).setStatus(eItemStatus.REJECTED);
                        r.ItemList[index].item.get(i).setRejectReason(rejectReason);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }) 
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // No additional code required at this time.
                }
            });
            //ab.show();

            AlertDialog dialog = ab.create();
            dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer!  From what I've researched, the buttons on an alertdialog use their own layout that cannot be overridden, so I ended up subclassing Dialog and building a custom dialog myself.

CustomDialog.java:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
TextView tvTitle;
TextView tvMessage;
Button btnOK;
ListView listView;
Context context;
ProgressBar prgWait;
ProgressBar prgBar;

public CustomDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.rtg_DialogActivity);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    this.context = context;

    // replace the background dim with a background blur effect
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.dimAmount = 0.0f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);

    tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDialogTitle);
    tvMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDialogMessage);
    btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDialog);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDialogList);
    prgWait = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgDialog);
    prgBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgDialogBar);
}

public CustomDialog setTitle(String text) {
    tvTitle.setText(text);      
    return this;
}

public CustomDialog setMessage(String text) {
    tvMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tvMessage.setText(text);        
    return this;
}

public CustomDialog setList(List<String> list, OnItemClickListener l) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    listView.setAdapter(aa);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(l);         
    return this;
}

public CustomDialog setList(String[] list, OnItemClickListener l) {
    List<String> lString = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : list)
        lString.add(s);     
    return setList(lString, l);
}

public CustomDialog setButton(String text, View.OnClickListener l) {
    btnOK.setText(text);
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(l);
    return this;
}

public CustomDialog setButton(String text) {
    return setButton(text, this);
}

public CustomDialog isIndeterminate(boolean b) {
    if (b) {
        prgWait.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnOK.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        prgWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnOK.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return this;
}

public CustomDialog isProgress(boolean b) {
    if (b) {
        prgBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnOK.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        prgBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnOK.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return this;
}

public CustomDialog setProgressMax(int max) {
    prgBar.setMax(max);
    return this;
}

public CustomDialog setProgress(int progress) {
    prgBar.setProgress(progress);
    return this;
}

public int getProgressMax() {
    return prgBar.getMax();
}

public int getProgress() {
    return prgBar.getProgress();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    this.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: OMG! That would be too simple... Haven't you found something easier?

Comment: @autowaaagh Could you please elaborate on that " use their own layout that cannot be overridden". As I understand this means that alert dialog buttons (button row) cannot be styled. Am I correct about this?

Answer (score 8):

Something I just tried that works. You can use getButton(int whichButton) in order to extract the Button's View class and then you can butcher it however you want.

Before you do this, call the .show() function, otherwise the Button themselves won't be created yet, and the getButton() command gives you null, and NullPointerExceptions suck. After you get the button, you can do Button/TextView (Button is an extended TextView) functions like .setBackgroundDrawable and .setTextColor.

```
AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
// configure things here like the title and message
alert.show();

Button button = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.negative_button_selector);
```

If someone can figure out how to set a style/theme outside creating a new Button and swiping that button's stuff, I'm all ears because that would be better.

Rock! Rock On!

Comment: Not bad! Though you can't style the title (especially the divider line) with this solution...

Comment: There is, however, one thing to consider - `getButton()` will return `null` until `show()` is called (this is a bug). Most of the time this is not a problem, but sometimes it is - e.g. when using `DialogFragment`. In this case workaround is to add `OnShowListener` and call `getButton()` inside it.

Comment: Oh cool. I didn't know about OnShowListener, and can add that to my bag of tricks

Comment: Not bad?  This is great!  It was exactly what I was looking for.  Far simpler than writing a replacement class just to style the buttons.